# How can i wrap an HOC around const export "function"

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I have an HOC called `withErrorHandler` which takes a component and the `axios` it uses and it adds error handler to it, this is easy with normal components

```
export default withErrorHandler(myComponent, axios);
```

But i don't know how to do the same when the export syntax and functions are like this :

```
//how can i wrap an hoc around this?
export const authenticationService = {
  login,
  logout,
  currentUser: currentUserSubject.asObservable(),
  get currentUserValue() { return currentUserSubject.value }
};

function login(username, password) {}

function logout() {}
```

**Update 01:**
My HOC component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
// import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

// function PaperComponent(props) {
//     return (
//         <Draggable cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
//             <Paper {...props} />
//         </Draggable>
//     );
// }

const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({ error: null });
                return req;
            });

            axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({ error: error });
            });
        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = (event) => {
            this.setState({ error: null });
        }

        render() {
            console.log('inside with error handler')
            return (
                <React.Fragment>

                    <Dialog
                        open={this.state.error}
                        onClose={this.errorConfirmedHandler}
                        //PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
                        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
                    >
                    <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
                            خطا
                    </DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <DialogContentText>
                                {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                            </DialogContentText>
                        </DialogContent>
                    </Dialog>

                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

Comment: Why do you need an HOC around `authenticationService` object ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit So if the login fails or if any other services fails, i get a dialog box saying "Network error", i use `axios interceptors` to intercept and if there is an error i show a dialog box

Comment: then convert `authenticationService` to a function like `authenticationService = (fn1, fn2) => ({login, logout})` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, Oh, so then i have to export it like, `export default withErrorHandler(authenticationService (fn1, fn2), axios)` ?

Comment: Oh.. no just `withErrorHandler(authenticationService, axios)`. In this case, `authenticationService` can be an object as you have right not, no need to turn it to a function. I thought something else.

Comment: After exporting the object, when i try login i get an error: `TypeError: _services_authentication_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__.default.login is not a function`, maybe i should share my HOC component so you get a better idea?

Comment: `AuthenticationService` is not a component, so you can't wrap it in a HOC.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Then what do you suggest i do to get the same interface and be able to use `withErrorHandler` ?